# Nested Namespace: accessing value from the inside namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

I am using nested namespace in C++ and trying to access the value of outer namespace inside inner namespace and it is not working? Can some one please explain why?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace Test
{
    int x = 20;
    namespace InTest
    {
        int x = 30 + x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace Test::InTest;
    cout << "X = " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
X = 30
```

For the above code snippet I am expecting value of x as '50' but I get '30'. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

OS: windows, 
Tool: Codeblocks
compiler: g++ (mingw)

Comment: In that case you should change the inner line to `int x = 30 + Test::x;` to explicitly specify the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `x=30` because you are accessing `Test::InTest::x`, as stated by your `using namespace` statement. The line

`int x = 30 + x;`

is equivalent to

`int x = 30 + 0;`

since the value of `Test::InTest::x` is zeroed upon initialisation (thanks Anton).

Now, if you want to add `Test::x`to `Test::InTest::x`, just say so.

`int x = 30 + Test::x;`

Comment: No, in this case `0` is not random, it's specified by language standard.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I guess you learn something new every day. Could you refer me to the c++ std section about this? I'd really like to check it out.

Comment: `[basic.start.init]/2`: Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
before any other initialization takes place.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 30 + x;
```

`x` on the right side of expression refers to `Test::InTest::x` because it is considered already declared. So you add 30 to the `x` own value, which is equal to `0` at startup because of zero-initialization of static objects (it takes place before any other initialization according to `[basic.start.init]/2`).